# How to upload a file to a server, that's not in the inventory?

Tags: ansible, sftp, scp

Sometimes we need to upload logs of an application, that's distributed among multiple local Unix machines, to the vendor's server. The machines are all part of the same inventory, and can perform the archiving of the logs, and uploading the archives directly.

The server runs Unix and accepts only SCP and SFTP, so `synchronize` module (which uses `rsync`) will not work.

There exists a `net_put`-module, but that seems intended for uploads to special network appliances -- trying to use it, I get cryptic errors about `ansible_network_os`...

I can, of course, use the `command` module, but is not there something specifically targeted for SCP- and/or SFTP-servers?

Comment: Given your requirement, using scp or sftp with the command module seems to be the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no module for scp or sftp, and I don't really see that it would provide a lot of value. sftp and scp are straightforward to use with `command`, and the underlying commands don't really support the things you might want a module to do, like skipping an upload if the file on the remote wouldn't change.

Comment: I could see, how [paramiko](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html) could be used intelligently, and skip uploads based on timestamps and file-sizes (as `rsync` would). But, if no one has done it yet, I'll use `command` :(